# Leer JSON con Php

Tags: php, json

Buenas un saludo a todos, tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy empezando en el mundo de php y json y estoy intentando capturar valores de una respuesta json. Me gustaria saber o aprender como acceder a cada uno de los valores. Les dejo en copia la respuesta. Gracias de antemano.

```
[{'Code':'202'},{'Mesagge':'Success'},{'Data':{"TravelItinerary":{"ItineraryRef":{"Type":14,"ID":"UIYJBK"},"CustomerInfos":{"CustomerInfo":[{"RPH":1,"Customer":{"PassengerTypeCode":"ADT","PersonName":{"Surname":"VERENZUELA DE RONDON","GivenName":"INAIL"},"Document":{"DocType":"PP","DocID":"056747216"},"ContactPerson":{"Telephone":"PTY 0414-153-6959 CHINCHILLA INTERNACIONAL NB","Email":"VIAJESCHINCHILLASCAROLINA@GMAIL.COM"}}}]},"ItineraryInfo":{"ReservationItems":{"Item":[{"ItinSeqNumber":1,"Air":{"Reservation":{"DepartureDateTime":"\/Date(1606854600000)\/","FlightNumber":"1215","ResBookDesigCode":"B","DepartureAirport":{"LocationCode":"SDQ"},"ArrivalAirport":{"LocationCode":"CCS"},"MarketingAirline":"9V"}}}]},"ItineraryPricing":{"ItemRPHList":"01","Cost":{"AmountBeforeTax":137,"AmountAfterTax":218.33},"Taxes":{"Tax":[{"TaxCode":"AA","Amount":20,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"C2","Amount":1.25,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"DO","Amount":24.66,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"EU","Amount":1.37,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"TY","Amount":2.75,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"UX","Amount":15,"CurrencyCode":"USD"},{"TaxCode":"VB","Amount":16.3,"CurrencyCode":"USD"}]}},"Ticketing":{"TicketingStatus":3,"TicketingTimeLimit":"\/Date(-62135582400000)\/"}}},"EchoToken":"1","TimeStamp":"\/Date(1603990120000)\/","Target":"Production","Version":"3.0","SequenceNmbr":1,"Error":null}}]
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: Hay funciones de PHP para tratar este tipo de cadenas. Coméntanos que has hecho hasta ahora, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertirlo en un objeto de esta manera `$objeto = json_decode($json);` y accederias a el de esta forma `$objeto->propiedad;`
o convertirlo en array de esta manera `$array = json_decode($json, true)` el parametro true hace referencia a `assoc` que es un parametro de la funcion para crear arrays asociativos es decir que para acceder a el sera de esta manera
`$array['propiedad'];`